# How to work with 2 ArrayList in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

firstly, I have reviewed all the answers, below.
But my problem still continues.

[How to sort 2 dependent ArrayLists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55573584/how-to-sort-2-dependent-arraylists)

[Add Multiple ArrayLists to RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29205965/add-multiple-arraylists-to-recyclerview)

[arraylist add to new recyclerview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52238177/arraylist-add-to-new-recyclerview)

[how to work with Multidimensional arraylist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20862515/how-to-work-with-multidimensional-arraylist)

[How to work with Java ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27493402/how-to-work-with-java-arraylist)

[how to search arraylist data in recyclerview in fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55447068/how-to-search-arraylist-data-in-recyclerview-in-fragment)

[How putExtra in RecyclerView with arraylist from JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51064310/how-putextra-in-recyclerview-with-arraylist-from-json)

[Print 2 ArrayLists with specific format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47653351/print-2-arraylists-with-specific-format)

I did the following, the way. But my application opens, and it closes immediately.

MainActivity.java

```
ArrayList<String> ulkeler = new ArrayList<>();
ulkeler.add("TÜRKİYE");
ulkeler.add("RUSYA");
ulkeler.add("FRANSA");
ulkeler.add("İNGİLTERE");
ulkeler.add("JAPONYA");
ulkeler.add("ALMANYA");


ArrayList<String> ulkelertwo = new ArrayList<>();
ulkeler.add("TÜRKİYEw");
ulkeler.add("RUSYAw");
ulkeler.add("FRANSAw");
ulkeler.add("İNGİLTEREw");
ulkeler.add("JAPONYAw");
ulkeler.add("ALMANYAw");

adapter = new MyAdapter(this,ulkeler,ulkelertwo);
rv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

onBindViewHolder

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull one holder, int position) {
    String ulke = ulkelerListe.get(position);
    String ulketwo = ulkelerListetwo.get(position);

    holder.textView.setText(ulke);
    holder.textViewtwo.setText(ulketwo);



}
```

getItemCount
    public int getItemCount() {

```
    return ulkelerListe.size()+ulkelerListetwo.size();
}
```

Logcat

https://github.com/prensmiskin/vollley-one/issues/2#issue-507813748

I did the following, taking advantage of the answer, but it didn't work.
[Two ArrayList one RecyclerView Adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42450466/two-arraylist-one-recyclerview-adapter)

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: ulkelertwo is empty.

Comment: Hi, Walid, thank you for your answer. I realized my fault, thanks to your answer. No problem, it worked. /  ulkelertwo.add("TÜRKİYEw");

Comment: Is it working? How it's possible?

Comment: hello, Md. Asaduzzaman, yes, it works.
Why wouldn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

Size of GetItemCount() is more than the list itemspassed for binding to recycler view. During getting the data at index which is not in the list causes exception.

Answer (score 0):

To make this working in your approach, you have to ensure  two things:

1. `ulkeler` and `ulkelertwo` must have same size.
2. Return `ulkelerListe.size` only from `getItemCount()`